# How to increase max heap size of Java 6?

Tags: java, caching, jetty, ehcache, heap-memory

I have Java 6 web application(*.war) running on Jetty 8. In application I am caching(with EHCache) some data, but I need to increase max heap size because 1g is not enough. I need min 2g and max 4g.

The question is: how to setup this (if it is possible - step by step)?

(I was trying "java -Xmx4g -Xms2g" but it respond me that I need to specify file with main method which is imposible for war)

Comment: See http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/chghelp/v5m3/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.rational.change.install.doc%2Ftopics%2Fch_t_ig_change_java_max_heap_jty.html

Comment: I tried but i had problem with finding -Xmx in jetty.sh file in step 3 for UNIX

"3. Search for the Java maximum heap size flag -Xmx, and then increase the value to a number more suitable to your needs."

Comment: Well see if you can find where flags are specified in general, and add it there. Perhaps it isn't present yet.

Comment: hmm...tried to do so, but no result. Need more specific answer, but thanks.

Comment: Please edit your question to show *exactly* what you've tried then. The more information you give, the more people are likely to be able to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start jetty like this:

```
java -Xms2G -Xmx4G -jar start.jar
```